# Подсветка синтаксиса c++11 отсутствует

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено

У [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523918/184217) вопроса есть тег [c++11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), но нет тега [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). В итоге подсветка синтаксиса не работает. Надо бы уравнять теги в правах.

Comment: подсветка не зависит от меток вопроса

Comment: а хотя да, действительно метками, интересно :)

Comment: Вроде бы все работает.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сейчас там явный хинт на `lang-cpp`. [Посмотрите без него](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/523918/1).

Comment: Посмотрел. Действительно, почему–то парсер не может понять, что это С++. Добавил в базу дефектов! Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky нет же, просто у метки [tag:c++-11] нету языка по умолчанию, а у [tag:c++] есть, `lang-cpp`. Тут вмешательство разработчиков не потребуется, я полагаю :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Язык кода в вопросе определяется по меткам. Для этого у меток должен быть проставлен соответствующий им язык (когда это возможно). Назначенное соответствие можно увидеть на странице описания метки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info

Сейчас я выставил метке язык `lang-cpp`. Проверьте, верно подсвечивается?

Comment: [Проверяем](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/523918/1). Вроде порядок :)